# How to implement Voting for Grails Domain Classes?

Tags: grails, frameworks, grails-orm, voting, voting-system

I have a Book class and need to implement a yes/no voting functionality. My domain classes look like this:

```
class Book {
   String title
   static hasMany = [votes: Vote]
}

class User {
  String name
  static hasMany = [votes: Vote]
}

class Vote {
  boolean yesVote
  static belongsTo = [user: User, book: Book]
}
```

What is the best way to implement a voting for the book class. I need the following informations:

- What is the average yesVote for a book over all votes (either yes or no)?
- How to check if a specific user has done a vote?

What is the best way to implement the computation of the average yesVote such that the performance does not drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a totalVotes to Book.  Incremenent that for each yes vote.  Then a simple count() of votes for a book along with the totalVotes value gives you what you need.

Update: Answering your comment questions:

1. `def yesVotes = Vote.findAllByBookAndYesVote(bookInstance, Boolean.TRUE)`
2. `def votes = Vote.findAllByBook(bookInstance)`
3. `def userVote = Vote.findByUserAndBook(userInstance, bookInstance)`

Comment: In your way you cannot see if a specific user has voted and if he voted yes or no. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, those are 2 different things.  You had 2 bullet points and then asked one question.  I assumed you knew you could simply do a Vote.findAllByUserAndYesVote(user, Boolean.TRUE) along with other variations of the same query.  If you're asking for something more complex, you should update your question.

Comment: can you provide some code for your example. I need to answer the following questions: 1. What is the number of yesVotes for a specific book? 2. What is the number of total votes for this book? 3. Has a current user voted for a specific book and what was his voting result? What is the list of books a user voted yes for? By the way would you do the voting class in the same way as I did? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have user instance. How can I get all books from user.books which where rated with yesVote by user?

Comment: You really need to start reading some Grails documentation. def yesVotes = Vote.findAllByUserAndYesVote(userInstance, Boolean.TRUE) and then you could do def books = yesVotes.collect { it.book }

Answer (score 0):

Well, my opinion is :

1. First way - One Service with a method addVote(user, book, true/false), and two others methods addPositiveVote(user, book) and addNegativeVote(user, book);
2. Second way - the business rules shoud be in the domains, put a method addVote in the book addVote(user, true/false).

This a simple process, the performance dont drop, my considerations only contemplate the modeling.

Sorry for my bad english.